# Amazon S3 SelectObjectContent error - OverMaxParquetBlockSize

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use the select functionality of S3 but for some files, I get OverMaxParquetBlockSize error.

My select is pretty simple:

```
r = s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket='prod-bucket',
    Key='810217_0',
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    Expression="select s.* from s3object s where s.\"id\" = 3744469",
    InputSerialization = {'Parquet': {}},
    OutputSerialization = {'JSON': {
                            "RecordDelimiter": "\n",
                                  }},
)
```

And this is the full error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (OverMaxParquetBlockSize) when calling SelectObjectContent operation: Parquet file is above the max block size
```

Is there any way to workaround this or to find more information about this limitation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the [S3 Select docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/selecting-content-from-objects.html), this is a hard limit - the uncompressed block size cannot exceed 256MB.

The only 'workaround' I can think of it to write Parquet files with a smaller block size, but that might not always be a realistic option.

Answer (score 0):

Shard your files vertically and query them seperately as page. The Hard limit of S3 Select is 256MB of Uncompressed data.